# Is there an ida plugin that disassemble in visual c inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, ida

I have a question... Is there an ida plugin that disassemble the file  in visual c inline assembly? I found this 
https://github.com/binrapt/ida
but when I load it in ida, it complains about "No module named nil.file"... Where can I find this "nil.file"? I searched in the web but I can't find anything ahah

Comment: What do you mean with "disassemble in Visual C inline assembly"? VC++ inline assembly is just regular x86 assembly in Intel/MASM syntax, which should be pretty much the same as what IDA uses by default.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it settle me the environment with "declspec (naked) { __asm { etc... I want to compile the code in visual studio.